# How to pipe to another task in Gulp?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I try to DRY my gulpfile. There I have small duplication of code I not comfortable with. How can this be made better?

```js
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.coffee')
    .pipe(coffeelint())
    .pipe(coffeelint.reporter())
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'))
    .pipe(gulp.src('src/index.html'))  // this
    .pipe(includeSource())             // needs
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))          // DRY
});

gulp.task('index', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(includeSource())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});
```

I got `index` as a separate task, since I need to watch `src/index.html` to livereload. But I'm also watching my `.coffee` sources and when they change, I need to update `src/index.html` as well.

How can I pipe to `index` in `scripts`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Gulp tasks synchronously/one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-synchronously-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score 25):

`gulp` enables you to order a series of tasks based on arguments.

Example:

```js
gulp.task('second', ['first'], function() {
   // this occurs after 'first' finishes
});
```

Try the following code, you will be running the task 'index' to run both tasks:

```js
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.coffee')
    .pipe(coffeelint())
    .pipe(coffeelint.reporter())
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'));
});

gulp.task('index', ['scripts'], function() {
  return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(includeSource())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});
```

The task `index` will now require `scripts` to be finished before it runs the code inside it's function.

Comment: I will try this approach as soon as I can.

Comment: and what if `scripts` will run, and there is a need to run `index` right after `scripts`?

Comment: I prefer to use `run-sequence` to orchestrate my tasks, so in general this solution is correct - separate repeating job into own gulp.task.

Comment: @vsync then you would make a task which calls index the same way index calls scripts. it will chain together very nicely so you can call just one task from the console. in this case 'gulp index'

Comment: Save stream to disk to load it in another task? This pattern looks a lot more "grunty" than "gulpy".

Comment: This 100% does not work. I get the following error `AssertionError: Task function must be specified`

Comment: As I understand and have tested, gulp just checks that `[index]` starts after `[scripts]`, not that `[scripts]` has finished gulping.

So in the case:
`gulp.task('2',['1'], function() { whatever() });`

Gulp will run 1, and just after 1 has started it will run 2. Runsequence is better to fix this, or even a check if 1 has really finished and just then trigger 2. Or like @gerardo-lima said, little grunty way.

Comment: @Bjorn need to add gulp.series(['first']) instead ['first']

Answer (score 3):

If you look into the Orchestrator source, particularly the `.start()` implementation you will see that if the last parameter is a function it will treat it as a callback.

I wrote this snippet for my own tasks:

```
  gulp.task( 'task1', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task2', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task3', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task4', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task5', () => console.log(a) )

  function runSequential( tasks ) {
    if( !tasks || tasks.length <= 0 ) return;

    const task = tasks[0];
    gulp.start( task, () => {
        console.log( `${task} finished` );
        runSequential( tasks.slice(1) );
    } );
  }
  gulp.task( "run-all", () => runSequential([ "task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "task5" ));
```