# Gulp: Synchronicity without dependency

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm migrating my build system over to gulp, and have encountered a problem:

I have defined various build tasks (`scripts`, `style`, `jade`, etc), as well as a `clean` task that removes all of the built files.

I want to make sure that the build tasks don't run before the clean tasks, **BUT** I also want to be able to run the build tasks without cleaning first.

i.e. I want:

`gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'scripts', 'style', 'jade']);`

To only start running `scripts`, `style` and `jade` after `clean` has finished, but

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){

  gulp.watch('path/to/stylus', ['css']);

});
```

Should not trigger `clean` to be run, which would be the case if `css` had a dependency on `clean`.

Comment: I don't know gulp, but I do know the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module by caolan. If it's possible to use gulp inside functions with async. You can be helped by [async.auto](https://github.com/caolan/async#auto) which has a natural notation for dependencies of asynchronous jobs to be finished. Do function C only when A and B are done. And do D when C is done.

Comment: In some cases I don't know how to get rid of `gulp.run`, in this case for example.

Comment: They removed the run method...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gulp. can't figure how to run tasks synchronously after each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/gulp-cant-figure-how-to-run-tasks-synchronously-after-each-other)

Comment: @Mathletics This is NOT a duplicate due to the second part of the question:  _"I also want to be able to run the build tasks without cleaning first."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the same problem:

```
...
var sequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('dev', ['css', 'js', 'html']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {

    gulp.watch(src.css, ['css']);
    gulp.watch(src.js, ['js']);
    gulp.watch(src.html, ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', function(done) {

    sequence('clean', 'dev', 'watch', done);
});
```

https://www.npmjs.org/package/run-sequence

Please, read:

> This is intended to be a temporary solution until orchestrator is updated to support non-dependent ordered tasks.

BTW, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/145185/overzealous!