# Gulp: Cannot get tasks to run synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, build-process, gulp

I have a `clean` task that I want to finish before running my build tasks.
No matter what I tried, I cannot get it to work properly: `clean` starts, `build tasks` starts, `clean` finishes (and throw an error because some folder is being written to) while build tasks are still running.

Here's some of my task definitions:

```
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'build']);
gulp.task('js', ['phnxjs', 'vendorsjs']);
gulp.task('css', ['phnxcss', 'vendorscss']);
gulp.task('assets', ['fonts', 'images', 'templates']);
gulp.task('build', ['js', 'css', 'assets', 'login']);
gulp.task('index', ['build'], index); <-- index is a function defined elsewhere

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src('**/*', targetOptions)
        .pipe(filters.excludeWebInf)
        .pipe(g.rimraf());
});
```

***ALL* my tasks returns a stream**

I also tried calling the `callback function` from the `clean` task instead of returning a stream, to no avail.

I even gave `run-sequence` a try, like so:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    run('clean', 'build', 'index');
});
```

It seems to yields better results but looks like it's missing a step as `index` isn't executed

---

**edit:** Tried tons of "task dependency" combinations, amongst which I tried to have `task('build', ['clean', 'js' ...]`

Still won't work with that scenario:

```
[13:46:32] Starting 'clean'...
[13:46:32] Starting 'phnxjs'...                   <-------- Clean not finished, other tasks started
[13:46:33] Starting 'vendorsjs'...
[13:46:33] Starting 'phnxcss'...
[13:46:33] Starting 'vendorscss'...
[13:46:33] Starting 'fonts'...
[13:46:33] Starting 'images'...
[13:46:33] Starting 'templates'...
[13:46:33] Starting 'login'...
[13:46:33] Starting 'index'...
[13:46:34] Finished 'vendorscss' after 1.2 s
[13:46:34] Finished 'login' after 1.1 s
[13:46:34] Finished 'index' after 1.09 s
[13:46:35] Finished 'fonts' after 2.7 s
[13:46:35] Finished 'images' after 2.7 s
[13:46:35] 'clean' errored after 3.1 s             <--------- Clean Error
[13:46:35] Error in plugin 'gulp-rimraf' 
ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/oclement/Documents/phoenix/MedifastCerBrokenDown/MedifastWeb/build/WebContent/app/generated'
[13:46:35] Finished 'templates' after 2.72 s
[13:46:36] Finished 'phnxcss' after 3.46 s
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342030/gulp-synchronicity-without-dependency/24342064#24342064

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gulp. can't figure how to run tasks synchronously after each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/gulp-cant-figure-how-to-run-tasks-synchronously-after-each-other)

Comment: This is probably the most common Gulp question on SO.

Comment: I did saw these questions and answers, and I did try all these solutions, to no avail.

Comment: @OlivierClément did you figure it out?

Comment: @DominicTobias Havent played in there in a while, but long story short, the tasks defined in the array (gulp.task('name', ['list', 'of', 'tasks], function() {});) are all executed in parallel. So you have to work around this.
Putting: ['clean', 'build'] while have both task running at the same time, which obviously does't make sense

Comment: @OlivierClément Thanks I ended up using run-sequence, perhaps it wasn't working for you because I am passing the function arg `cb` as the last param of the run call?

Answer (score 0):

`build` needs to have `clean` as a dependency.

```
// -----------------v
gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'js', 'css', 'assets', 'login']);
```

Comment: My bad, forgot to add I also tried that - will amend the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code...

```
  gulp.task( 'task1', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task2', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task3', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task4', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task5', () => console.log(a) )

  function runSequential( tasks ) {
    if( !tasks || tasks.length <= 0 ) return;

    const task = tasks[0];
    gulp.start( task, () => {
        console.log( `${task} finished` );
        runSequential( tasks.slice(1) );
    } );
  }
  gulp.task( "run-all", () => runSequential([ "task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "task5" ));
```