# gulp.run() has been deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, gulp

I am using gulp. I want to run 'connect task after the 'build-dev' task has done.
Here is what I wrote:

```
gulp.task('dev', [ 'build-dev' ], function() {
    return gulp.run([ 'connect' ]);
});
```

This causes a warning:

```
gulp.run() has been deprecated. Use task dependencies or gulp.watch task triggering instead.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create "connect" as a new task with a dependency on "build-dev" and "dev"?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26390567/125680

Edit: ok, got you.

According to this:

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/96

There's no set way to do this in gulp yet so they recommend the run-sequence module:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/run-sequence

Comment: connect can't be dependency on build-dev because it can run also after build-staging.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to use promises:

```
var build = function() {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        // assuming usage like 'build(args, callback)'
        build(args, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('build failed');
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('build succeeded');
                fulfill();
            }
        });
    });
};
var connect = function() {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        // assuming usage like 'connect(address, callback)'
        connect(address, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('connect failed');
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('connect succeeded');
                fulfill();
            }
        });
    });
};
gulp.task('dev', function() {
    return build().then(function() {
        return connect();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

To Use task dependencies, you should rewrite this:

```
gulp.task('dev', [ 'build-dev' ], function() {
  return gulp.run([ 'connect' ]);
});
```

to this:

```
gulp.task('dev', [ 'build-dev', 'connect' ]);
```

Comment: This is not true: The first example has 'connect' run AFTER 'build-dev'. The second has them run in parallel.