# Error No such file or directory during Gulp-Ruby-Sass Task

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I'm using [Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) as my task runner, and **[gulp-ruby-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass)** to compile my sass files into css.

The error I'm getting on my `gulp default` task:

[image]

**My default Gulp task:**

```
gulp.task('default', ['delete', 'web_css', 'dash_css', 'web_js', 'dash_js']);
```

My 2 compile SASS tasks:

```
// Compile public SASS
gulp.task('web_css', function() {
    return sass('client/website/_sources/sass/bitage_web.scss', { style: 'compressed' })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/website/assets/css'));
});

// Compile dashboard SASS
gulp.task('dash_css', function() {
    return sass('client/dashboard/_sources/sass/bitage_app.scss', { style: 'compressed' })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/dashboard/assets/css'));
});
```

Both tasks above are virtually identically.

**When I run the default task (`gulp`):**

1. The website css compiles ok
2. All the js compiles ok
3. But then I get that error before the `dash_css` finishes, and the
   css is not compiled :(

[image]

***Additional notes:***

- If make a change in `gulp watch` the `dash_css` will compile just
  fine.
- If I run just `gulp dash_css` it also compiles just fine.
- I only have this `Errno::ENOENT` bug when I run the default task.

[image]

**Do you see anything strange above? Or have run into this issue before?**

Comment: Try disabling `delete` task. If that prevents the error include it in the question.

Comment: @Heikki hey you are on to something, removing the `delete` didn't work, but I rearranged things and made `dash_css` the first task and there wasn't any error! Only now it's putting stuff in the wrong folders.. double checking

Comment: Ok so with delete removed and dash_css made the first function, it's putting both compiled css files into the website > assets > css directory. Now I'm thinking I need some pipes in my default task to watch the order of things perhaps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144068/sequencing-tasks-with-gulp/28147701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback so that gulp knows when the task is complete:

```
gulp.task('delete', function(cb) {
    del([
        'client/website/assets/css/maps',
        'client/website/assets/css/bitage_web.css',
        'client/dashboard/assets/css/maps',
        'client/dashboard/assets/css/bitage_app.css',
        'client/website/assets/js/*',
        'client/dashboard/assets/js/*'
    ], cb);
});
```

Make `delete` run before other tasks for example with [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence).

Comment: Thanks! I think `run-sequence` is the key, right now both css files are getting compiled into both dash and web directories... but at least no more error :)

Answer (score -1):

I've changed

```
gulp.task('web_css', function() {
    return sass(....
```

to:

```
gulp.task('web_css', function() {
    return gulp.src('
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code answers, also provide some commentary on what your code is doing.