# Run gulp task after completion of other task

Tags: javascript, gulp, synchronous

I have two sets of files, let's call them `base` and `mods`. The `mods` files override the `base` files, so when I run the gulp task related to `base`, I need to run the `mods` task directly after. My setup is something like this:

```
gulp.task('base',function(){
  return gulp.src('base-glob')
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out-glob'))
});

gulp.task('mods',function(){
  return gulp.src('mods-glob')
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out-glob'))
});
```

So I want to run the `mods` task at the completion of the `base` task. Note that this is not the same as defining `base` as a dependency of `mods`, because if I'm only changing `mods` files, I only need to run the `mods` task. I'd prefer not to use a plugin.

I've been reading the docs about callback functions and other suggestions of synchronous tasks, but can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements. You want `mods` to run AFTER `base` but you only want `mods` to run by itself if only `mods` files are changed? That doesn't make sense exactly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I have two use cases: when `base` files change, I want to run `base` then `mods`. When `mods` files change I only want to run `mods`.

Comment: I figured as much just wanted to make sure. See my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Gulp tasks synchronously/one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-synchronously-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you don't want to use a plugin, but gulp doesn't have a way to run a sequence of tasks in order without a plugin. [Gulp 4 will](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/355), but in the meantime the stopgap solution is the [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) plugin.

```
gulp.task('all', function() {
  runSequence('base', 'mods');
});
```

This ensures that the tasks run in order as opposed to unordered dependencies.

Now setup a watch:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('base-glob', ['all']);
    gulp.watch('mods-glob', ['mods']);
});
```

Whenever `base-glob` changes, gulp will run `all` task, which will run the sequence `base` then `mods`.

Whenever `mods-glob` changes, gulp will run only `mods` task.

That sound about right?

Comment: that worked for me, thank you!! worth noting there is a newer version of **gulp-run-sequence** which is called just [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

runSequence has some weird bugs, it kept complaining that my tasks are not defined.

If you look into the Orchestrator source, particularly the `.start()` implementation you will see that if the last parameter is a function it will treat it as a callback.

I wrote this snippet for my own tasks:

```
  gulp.task( 'task1', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task2', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task3', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task4', () => console.log(a) )
  gulp.task( 'task5', () => console.log(a) )

  function runSequential( tasks ) {
    if( !tasks || tasks.length <= 0 ) return;

    const task = tasks[0];
    gulp.start( task, () => {
        console.log( `${task} finished` );
        runSequential( tasks.slice(1) );
    } );
  }
  gulp.task( "run-all", () => runSequential([ "task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "task5" ));
```