# Use gulp.task in pipes?

Tags: gulp

Is it possible to define several tasks, e.g. less, typescript, etc, and then use them in another task?

I have a couple of tasks which are declared as individual tasks and which are executed by gulp *taskname*. But now I want to be able to create a default task which uses all of them in a pipeline manner.

Is it possible, or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: In general, I think gulp tasks are supposed to stand alone, or use a /tmp folder or something of that nature for intermediate building. You can also look into [run sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) which is create for sequencing multiple related tasks.

Comment: you can create a task which depends on all the common tasks.. and then use that task whenevr you need to run that task

Comment: Great thanks. Your answer led me to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-synchronously-one-after-the-other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post an answer here :)

Just as entre described and with an example here [How to run Gulp tasks sequentially one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-synchronously-one-after-the-other).