# gulp - How to concatenate multiple files with watch?

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, concatenation

I want to select a couple of files, and generate concatenated files from them. And also want to concatenate my changed files.
This is my assets tree:

```
assets
  - css
  - js
  - sass
    - _midia_queries.scss
    - media-combine.scss
    - query.scss
```

So, I want to generate **maximum.css**(*./assets/css/media-combine.min.css*) and **medium.css**(*./assets/css/media-combine.min.css*, *./assets/css/query.min.css*).

Both *.min* files are been generated by my **css** task. See below:

```
gulp.task('css', function (done) {
    gulp.src(paths.sass.src)
        .pipe(plugins.changed('dist'))
        .pipe(plugins.sass())
        .pipe(plugins.combineMediaQueries())
        .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer())
        .pipe( isProduction ? plugins.minifyCss() : gutil.noop() )
        .pipe( isProduction ? plugins.rename({ suffix: ".min" }) : gutil.noop() )
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.dest))
        .on("end", done);
});
```

And my **concat-css** task is using my bad approach of multiple generation files:

```
gulp.task('concat-css', ['css'], function (done) {
    concatType("css", done);
});

function concatType (type, done) {
    if (isProduction) {
        var task = gulp;
        filesToConcat[type].forEach(function (value) {
            value.files.forEach(function (file, fileIndex) {
                value.files[fileIndex] = paths[type].dest + file;
            });

            gutil.log('File', gutil.colors.green(value.compiled), 'is beign concatenated');
            task = gulp.src(value.files)
                .pipe(plugins.concat(value.compiled))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths[type].dest));
            gutil.log('Ready to go!');
        });
        task.on("end", done);
    }
}
```

## Update

When I type **gulp** on my console/terminal, it runs perfectly my **css** and **concat-css** tasks, but, when the **watch** tasks is triggered by a file change, both run, but, only **css** works. My *.min* files are updated, but, my concatenated files are not.
[image: Gulp file running]

Any ideas to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: Could this be due to the fact that gulp runs tasks simultaneously by default? Your css and css-concat tasks will likely be running at the same time. [This SO post may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-synchronously-one-after-the-other)

Comment: It helped. And I've made a few changes. So, now the only problem is when my *.scss* file is updated, it says it concats my files, but it won't happen.

Comment: Try only referencing the 'concat-css' script from the default and watch tasks as you will be running the css part twice otherwise. ie. `gulp.task("default", ['concat-css',  'watch']);` and `gulp.watch(paths.sass.src, ["concat-css"])`

Comment: I've tried it. It gives a better performance answer, but, still doesn't work at my watch task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a logic problem.

At my concatType function, when I was setting up the path for the targeted files, but, when it was running on watch the path was set a second time, like this:

> ./assets/css/./assets/css/query.min.css

It would never work. So, I've changed this:

```
 value.files.forEach(function (file, fileIndex) {
     value.files[fileIndex] = paths[type].dest + file;
 });

 task = gulp.src(value.files)
```

For this:

```
files = [];
value.files.forEach(function (file) {
    files.push(paths[type].dest + file);
});

task = gulp.src(files)
```