# Gulp clean folder then create folder

Tags: gulp

I have a pretty simple gulp task that I'm trying to accomplish:

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('build-dev', ['lint', 'jscs', 'clean-all', 'usemin'])

gulp.task('clean-all', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.dest, { read: false })
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('usemin', function () {
    return gulp.src('index.html')
      .pipe(usemin({
          css: [rev(), minifyCss, 'concat'],
          appjs: [uglify()],
          vendorjs: [uglify()]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest + '/'));
});
```

**gulp.config.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
var root = './app/';
var dest = './build/dist';
var bower = {
    json: require('./bower.json'),
    directory: './bower_components/'
};
var nodeModules = 'node_modules';

var config = {
    build: 'build/',
    root: root,
    dest: dest
};

return config;
```

};

It seems like when I run this if I have files in the `dist` folder then it will successfully clean the files out of it, but not complete the `usemin` task.  If I have a clean `dist` folder and run it then it will complete `usemin`

What am I missing so that it clears the folder, then re-creates it to place the `usemin` files in it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that due to asynchronously running of the tasks your defined tasks are not running simultaneously. You should try out this chain your tasks as it is described on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26390567/910701).

```
//fetch tasks
gulp.task('build-dev', ['lint', 'jscs', 'clean-all', 'usemin'])

gulp.task('clean-all', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.dest, { read: false })
        .pipe(clean());
});

//wait clean-all to exit
gulp.task('usemin', ['clean-all'], function () {
    return gulp.src('index.html')
      .pipe(usemin({
          css: [rev(), minifyCss, 'concat'],
          appjs: [uglify()],
          vendorjs: [uglify()]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest + '/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add in the `run-sequence` module and replace the `build-dev` task with something like this.

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence').use(gulp)
gulp.task('build-dev', function(cb){
  runSequence('clean-all', ['lint', 'jscs', 'usemin'], cb)
}
```

You don't want other tasks to be running while files are being deleted.