# Is it possible to run gulp tasks after linting?

Tags: gulp, eslint

I have a gulp task setup like so:

`gulp.task('dev', ['lint', 'dev:js', 'dev:css', 'fonts', 'connect', 'watch', 'browser']);`

I would like for the `lint` task to be run before any of the other tasks, but they all run asynchronously.

I understand that the `fn` argument for `gulp.task` would only be run after the dependencies run, so that seems like the ideal place to run all of the other tasks after `lint`, I'm just not sure how to do that with gulp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Gulp tasks synchronously/one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-synchronously-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gulp-sequence or run-sequence module.

Here's a example of gulp-sequence

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sequence

```
var gulpSequence = require('gulp-sequence');

gulp.task( 'dev', gulpSequence( 'lint', [ 'dev:js', 'dev:css', 'fonts', 'connect', 'watch', 'browser' ] ) );
```

It will run lint first, then all other async.