# gulp.watch does not run tasks in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

### Objective

Create a `gulp.watch` task to run others tasks in a specific order

### Why this is not a duplicate

Many people have suggested I take a look at [How to run Gulp tasks sequentially one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-synchronously-one-after-the-other). However, this question focuses on `gulp.task` while my question focuses on `gulp.watch`.

The solution I am searching is a way to use `gulp.watch` to achieve the synchronous effect I am after. If this is not possible however, I will fall-back to `gulp.task`.

### Background

I have a small project, I have some test files as well as the the gulp `gulp-complexity` plugin. I wish to run the test files first, and then run the `gulp-complexity` plugin every time a JavaScript file is changed.

### What I have tried

I read the documentation and saw the following tutorials:

- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/building-with-gulp/

They were very good, but I still don't understand how I can have a `gulp.watch` task that runs tasks in synchronously (in a specific order) instead of running them asynchronously.

### Code

This is what I got so far:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var mocha = require("gulp-mocha");
var complexity = require("gulp-complexity");

gulp.task("test", function(){
    gulp
    .src("./test.js")
    .pipe(mocha())
    .on("error", function(){
        this.emit("end");
    });
});


gulp.task("complexity", ["test"], function(){
    gulp.src('*.js').pipe(complexity());
});

gulp.task("watch", function(){
    gulp.watch("./*.js", ["test", "complexity"]);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Please bare in mind I am still very new to gulp (started learning it today!) so any explanations on my problem would be welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Gulp tasks synchronously/one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-synchronously-one-after-the-other)

Comment: i read that question and it didn't help because they don't use gulp.watch. Thanks for the suggestion thogh !

Comment: Edited my question to explain why it is not a duplicate!

Comment: Whether you use `gulp.watch()` or not doesn't matter. The answers in that question work for your case as well.

Comment: it matters to me. that's why I made the question :D

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, Sven is correct. The same answer for the `gulp.task()` thread applies to yours, because both `gulp.task` and `gulp.watch` accept an array of tasks to run that execute in exactly the same manner, essentially making the task and watch methods identical in terms of how they run tasks (whether you accept that or not). Your question is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: So, what is the difference between the two? They share the same bug? If you could an elaboration on that, I would pick your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Gulp issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/670) and should be be fixed in  [gulp 4.0](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/4.0)

For now, try  `run-sequence` [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence ]