# Gulp file processing in 2 iterations

Tags: typescript, gulp

I'm using `Gulp` to build my `Typescript` application for `Node.js`.

For my purposes I need to scan all `.ts` files, retrieve some information, and then append this information to some of `.ts` files.

I'm using `gulp-modify` to inject my file handler to the `pipe()`.

```
gulp.task(...., function() {
    return gulp.src('*.ts')
        .pipe(modify(statisticsProccesor))
        .pipe(modify(injectData))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(...))
});
```

Where `statisticsProccesor` and `injectData` are `function(file, content)` implementations to process exact file from sources stream.

Using this approach I can retrieve some statistics from sources. But I can not inject it back because `gulp.src()` processes all files one by one (and calls all handlers too).

Once I have 2 files `1.ts` and `2.ts` this task will process it in such order:

```
1.ts: statisticsProccesor(), injectData()
2.ts: statisticsProccesor(), injectData()
```

while I need to do such magic:

```
1.ts: statisticsProccesor()
1.ts: statisticsProccesor()
2.ts: injectData()
2.ts: injectData()
```

I've tried to add 2 `gulp.src().pipe(modify)` commands to the task. And also to separate these parts to 2 different tasks to launch one by one. But Gulp optimizes execution, so I can't preprocess sources and iterate them twice.

Comment: You **can** do this with two tasks. You just need to properly hint execution order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `Sven` it is necessary to breakdown task into few dependent tasks.

```
gulp.task('doGood, ['subDo'], function(callback) {
    gulp.src('*.ts')
        .pipe(modify(statisticsProccesor))
        .on('finish', callback);
});

gulp.task('subDo', function(callback) {
    gulp.src('*.ts')
        .pipe(modify(injectData))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(...));
});

gulp doGood
```

Few important things:

```
1. `subDo` should not return the stream
2. `subDo` should contain `on('finish')` instruction
```