# How to Pass Data OR communicate Between Two Dependent Gulp tasks?

Tags: gulp

i want to run task in sequence, but want to pass data from one task to another.

Here is my code.

Gulp task 1 -> compile Html

```
gulp.task('compile:html', function () {
return gulp.src(['src/templates/*.html', 'src/templates/*.template'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(nunjucksRender({
        data: templateConfig, //in templateConfig environment is saved
        path: ['src/templates/']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'));

});
```

Gulp Task 2 -> generate build

```
gulp.task('build:production', function (callback) {
var temp = templateConfig.env;
templateConfig.env = 'production';
gulp.start('compile:html');

setTimeout(function () {
    //gulp.src('./src/assets/**/*.*').pipe(gulp.dest('./generated/dist/production/assets'));
    gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(userRef())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/production'));

    templateConfig.env = temp;
    callback();
}, 2500);

});
```

currently i am using timeout in task 2 to give time for render templates according to environment.

task 2 (generate build) requirements

1. change environment in templateConfig, so template are generated accordingly
2. compile the template using task 1
3. wait for compilation to finish, can take long time
4. generate build to dist

Comment: Duplicate of [How to run Gulp tasks sequentially one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-sequentially-one-after-the-other)

Comment: its not duplicate, i want to run sequencially , but also want to pass data before sequence runs @SvenSchoenung

Comment: That doesn't really change anything. Put the second stream into its own task. Then run both tasks in sequence after changing `templateConfig`.

Comment: thanks will try that