# Add Vinyl FTP deploy to an existing gulp watch workflow

Tags: gulp, vinyl-ftp

I have little experience with Gulp and just want to be able to automatically upload my css file immediately after Gulp has created it from my SASS files through gulp watch:css

I've tried adding the 'deploy' task into the gulp watch:css task, but I cannot get the deploy task to run AFTER the CSS file is created. It always runs before.

Here's the relevant code where I have tried to add 'deploy' to the gulp watch:css task...

```
gulp.task('watch:css', ['styles', 'deploy'], function() {
  return gulp.watch(options.theme.sass + '**/*.scss', options.gulpWatchOptions, ['styles', 'deploy']);
});

gulp.task('styles', ['clean:css'], function() {
  return gulp.src(sassFiles)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass(options.sass).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer(options.autoprefixer))
    .pipe($.size({showFiles: true}))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.theme.css))
    .pipe($.if(browserSync.active, browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'})))
});

var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );
var ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

gulp.task( 'deploy', function () {

    var conn = ftp.create( {
        host:     'xxx.com',
        user:     'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        parallel: 10,
        log:      gutil.log
    } );

    var globs = [
      'css/styles.css'
    ];

    // using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly 
    // turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance 

    return gulp.src( globs, { base: '.', buffer: false } )
        .pipe( conn.newer( '/' ) ) // only upload newer files 
        .pipe( conn.dest( '/' ) );

} );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Gulp tasks sequentially one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-sequentially-one-after-the-other)

Comment: I can't tell from that how to run a Gulp task like watch:css that is always checking for changes and then adding the deploy task to run after watch:css every time.

I can get deploy to run after watch:css one time, but not every time I make a SASS change

Comment: The linked answers tell you how to make a task that runs stuff in sequence. The only thing they don't tell you is to call that task from your watch, but that should be obvious.

Comment: not obvious. very, very new to gulp and this is really the only thing I need to modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

the 'watch:css' task calls my 'deploy' task instead of 'styles':

```
gulp.task('watch:css', ['deploy'], function() {
  return gulp.watch(options.theme.sass + '**/*.scss', options.gulpWatchOptions, ['deploy']);
});
```

the 'styles' task remains as is

the 'deploy' task takes the 'styles' task as a dependency like this

```
gulp.task( 'deploy', ['styles'], function () {
```

Now when running 'gulp watch:css' it triggers the 'deploy' function on every change to my SASS files, which in turn triggers the 'styles' function that compiles my CSS.