# Gulp watch breaks production files

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, gulp-watch

So, I've come across a problem where running my gulp watch task breaks my build, however; this only occurs when I edit the `.scss` file and gulp detects the change.

For example, the styles have been applied correctly to a specific document on my website. I start watching my assets by invoking gulp. I run `gulp` to invoke the default task (which builds everything correctly, concatenates my assets, etc.)

This doesn't break my production file. It isn't until I edit the file, (and gulp detects that and runs the necessary tasks again) this occurs.

This is my gulpfile

```
//Node dependencies 
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    minifyJS = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    pump = require('pump'),
    sync = require('run-sequence');

//Sass transpilation task
gulp.task('sass', function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('app/scss/*.scss'),
    sass(),
    gulp.dest('app/css')
  ], cb);
});

//Uglify CSS task
gulp.task('ugCSS', function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('app/css/*.css'),
    minifyCSS(),
    rename({
      suffix: ".min"
    }),
    gulp.dest('dist/css')
  ], cb);
});

//Uglify JS task
gulp.task('ugJS', function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('app/js/*.js'),
    minifyJS(),
    rename({
      suffix: ".min"
    }),
    gulp.dest('dist/js')
  ], cb);
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  return gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', ['default']);
});

//Default task to make sure everythings runs syncronously
gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
  sync('sass', 'ugCSS', 'ugJS', 'watch', callback);
});
```

If what I've said hasn't made sense, I'll systematically list how I invoke this problem.

1. **gulp**: this runs the default task (this doesnt break styling)
2. **edit .scss file in ide**: I want to make a change to my styling, so I edit the file, the gulp watch task detects this and returns the 'default' task again, starting the cycle all over again.
3. **open browser and navigate to site to see applied styling**: this is where it breaks, all of my styling has been removed, the 'gulp.dest' file for my css (that I've uglified and passed into the distribution folder) is blank.
4. **gulp**: cancelling previous gulp process and running it again fixes the problem. Navigating back to css file in /dist - all the styles are there.

Long story short, my styles are ONLY removed when I 'actively' edit the `.scss` file and the gulp watch task invokes the necessary tasks to build the file into the production folder, so the relevant documents can see those changes.

Comment: instead of the 'default' task in watch do a test and run only 'sass' job to see if correctly compiles the styles

Comment: Tried that, same thing. If I run the sass task on its own as in gulp sass - that works fine.

If I run the watch task and the watch task detects a change and then runs the sass task, that's where it breaks.

Comment: I am facing a similar situation and I think the problem lies in the tasks not being done in sequential order. Pretty sure 'ugCSS' runs before 'sass' has done its job.

Comment: Well, that's why I included the 'runSequence' module, so I could specify which order the tasks would be executed. Watching gulp output the tasks that have 'started and finished' - it appears to run in correct order.

Comment: I recommend you don't call default with the watch as the default starts the watch and when you make a change you're repeatedly calling it. Instead just list what tasks you want, ie. ['sass', 'ugcss', ect..] . Just a quick note to make writing in gulp less prone to errors. In addition I suggest you use gulp-plumber in all your gulp tasks so your streams do not break on an error. Quick note: you don't need to include function(cb) and return cb in every task, you just need that with use of run-sequence, other tasks can just be function(). Best

Answer (score 1):

Being myself a newbie with gulp and having a similar issue which I solved by looking at: [How to run Gulp tasks sequentially one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-sequentially-one-after-the-other), here is something you could try:

```
//Sass transpilation task
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/*.scss') // return solved my problem
             .pipe(sass()/*.on('error', sass.logError)*/) // optional on error
             .pipe(dest('app/css'));
});

//Uglify CSS task
gulp.task('ugCSS', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/css/*.css')
             .pipe(minifyCSS())
             .pipe(rename({suffix: ".min"})
             .pipe(dest('dist/css'));
});

//Uglify JS task
gulp.task('ugJS', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
             .pipe(minifyJS())
             .pipe(rename({suffix: ".min"})
             .pipe(dest('dist/js'));
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  return gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', ['default']);
});

//Default task to make sure everythings runs syncronously
gulp.task('default', function() {
  sync('sass', 'ugCSS', 'ugJS');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem. I have tried to return chained methods too, but that doesn't work.

Also, I have removed synchronous execution as being a problem by using gulps deps argument they provide on the task method. 

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps

Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: Sorry if it does not work, just posted what worked for me