# Run external scripts in sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to run a couple of SQL scripts from Gulp:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const child_process = require('child_process');

function runSQLScript(script) {
    child_process.execFile('sqlcmd', [
        '-S', process.env.DB_SERVER,
        '-U', process.env.DB_USER,
        '-P', process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        '-d', process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        '-f', 'i:65001',
        '-i', script
    ], {
        cwd: '../sql/sqlcmd'
    }, function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log("" + stdout);
            console.error("" + error);
        }
        if (stderr.length>0) {
            console.error('' + stderr);
        }
    });
}

gulp.task('sql', ['install-app', 'load-data']);
gulp.task('install-app', function(){
    runSQLScript('install-app.sql');
});
gulp.task('load-data', function(){
    runSQLScript('load-data.sql');
});
```

Then I run:

```
gulp sql
```

In an earlier version I was using `child_process.execFileSync()` and my scripts were running in sequence as expected. I switched to `child_process.execFile()` to be able to report errors but now `load-data.sql` fails because it no longer waits for `install-app.sql` to finish.

What can I do to make the task wait until `runSQLScript()` finishes? Did I choose a wrong approach to print errors?

Comment: What version of gulp is this?

Comment: It's Gulp/3.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [gulp-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sequence) is the best choice to use (If your gulp version is < 4).

```
const util = require('util');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gulpSequence = require('gulp-sequence');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const execFile = util.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);

function runSQLScript(script) {
    return execFile('sqlcmd', [
        '-S', process.env.DB_SERVER,
        '-U', process.env.DB_USER,
        '-P', process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        '-d', process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        '-f', 'i:65001',
        '-i', script
    ], {
        cwd: '../sql/sqlcmd'
    }, function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log("" + stdout);
            console.error("" + error);
        }
        if (stderr.length>0) {
            console.error('' + stderr);
        }
    });
}

gulp.task('sql', gulpSequence('install-app', 'load-data'));
gulp.task('install-app', function(){
    return runSQLScript('install-app.sql');
});
gulp.task('load-data', function(){
    return runSQLScript('load-data.sql');
});
```

Comment: Does gulp-sequence figure out when calls to `child_process.execFile` complete?

Comment: I was actually looking at the documentation for that. From the docs, you may need to "promisfy" it. I'll post an updated code snippet

Comment: I've tried your code as-is and it seems to work. Not sure if it's robust but it definitively works in my specific use case.

Comment: Check the updated code. Looking [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) it seems you can use `util.promisfy` to make execFile return a promise.

Comment: Also, check out gulp 4.0. Seems you can do this quite easily with [`gulp.series`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31329150/4875631).

Comment: Can't verify it right now, `util.promisify(original)` was added in Node/8.0.0 and I'm currently using 6.9.5. But you've given me a lot of stuff to play with, thank you very much.

Comment: I've just learn why I (incorrectly) thought that the first version it was working. I had leftovers from previous tests where I was using [q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) to make `execFile()` return a promise. `gulp-sequence` was just the missing brick.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, switching from `.execFileSync()` to `.execFile()` appears to be the simplest way to capture the script output in all circumstances. On error, `.execFileSync()` no longer returns script stdout and there isn't an obvious way to fetch it; you can redirect it to process stdout but, then, you have the problem of fetching it from there if you need further processing. Verbose and illogical as it is, asynchronous code is the least evil.

You can then use `gulp-sequence()` as [FrankerZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44779644/13508) explains. As an alternative to `util.promisify()` (which requires Node/8) you can also use [q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) to make `child_process.execFile()` return a promise.

Additionally, it seems that you need to `catch()` the promise returned by `runSQLScript()`. Otherwise, the second scripts executes anyway, no matter the result of the prior script.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const child_process = require('child_process');
const Q = require('q');

function runSQLScript(script) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    child_process.execFile('sqlcmd', [
        '-S', process.env.DB_SERVER,
        '-U', process.env.DB_USER,
        '-P', process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        '-d', process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        '-f', 'i:65001',
        '-i', script
    ], {
        cwd: '../sql/sqlcmd'
    }, function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log("" + stdout);
            console.error("" + error);
            deferred.reject();
        } else {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
        if (stderr.length>0) {
            console.error('' + stderr);
        }

    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

gulp.task('sql', gulpSequence('install-app', 'load-data'));
gulp.task('install-app', function(callback){
    runSQLScript('install-app.sql')
        .then(function(){
            callback();
        })
        .catch(function(){
            callback("install-app failed, aborting");
        });
});
gulp.task('load-data', function(callback){
    runSQLScript('load-data.sql')
        .then(function(){
            callback();
        })
        .catch(function(){
            callback("load-data failed, aborting");
        });
});
```

Comment: You may want to use `deferred.reject()` for when `error !== null`.