# How to wait for task to end - Javascript

Tags: javascript, gulp

My code works but I have a 5 second timeout. The proper way would be to wait for the sequence to end and then build the jar.

Any help??

```
gulp.task('build-utility', function(cb) {
  runSequence('clean', ['scripts', 'vendor', 'html', 'i18n', 'css', 'webfonts', 'images'], cb);
   setTimeout(function() {
    gulp.start('jar');
   }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: what `gulp` version?

Comment: @IvanKaraman 3.9

Comment: checkout this solution, You can use .series function - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-sequentially-one-after-the-other

Comment: Why don't you add your task to the sequence? `runSequence('clean', ['scripts', 'vendor', 'html', 'i18n', 'css', 'webfonts', 'images'], 'jar', cb);`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `Promise` and wait to finish them.

Example:

```
gulp.task('build-utility', function(cb) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         runSequence('clean', ['scripts', 'vendor', 'html', 'i18n', 'css', 'webfonts', 'images'], cb);
    });

    gulp.start('jar');
});
```

Comment: Await is only valid in async function

Comment: @Tiago gulp.task is a async function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using callback mechanism

var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

```
gulp.task('develop', function(done) {
    runSequence('clean', 'coffee', function() {
        console.log('Run something else');
        done();
    });
});
```

Ref : [How to run Gulp tasks sequentially one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-sequentially-one-after-the-other)

Comment: Didn't work. It executes the console.log before finishing the other tasks

Comment: the sequence of tasks like 'scripts','vendors' etc ensure they either return a stream or promise, or handle the callback .If the final argument is a function, it will be used as a callback after all the functions are either finished or an error has occurred..  Ref : https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence